# garbage value while usage of unsigned long int

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()

{

    unsigned long int i=1902;

    int j=0;

    while(j<10)

    {

     i=i*10;

     printf("\n%lu",i);

     j++;

    }
}
```

Why am I getting correct results only upto 5 iterations? Please help me to get the correct answer for all iterations. Seeing the range, I changed my `int` to `unsigned long int` but still I'm unable to correct the error.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you're on a 32-bit system, *or* using the Microsoft Visual Studio compiler. I guess that because it seems that `unsigned long` is 32 bits, which means the maximum value it can be is a little over 4 billion.

If you want a 64-bit value then you need to use `unsigned long long`, which is 64 bits on just about all PC-like systems.

Answer (score 0):

Because at that point the value is out of the range that a unsigned long int can represent, that goes from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

Answer (score 0):

unsigned long int is 4 bytes in almost every C Compiler.

here i is initialized with 1902.
You are multiplying the value of i by 10 at each iteration.

The range of signed long int is from  -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
By making the variable unsigned you can only double the range of positive integers, ie, from  0 to 4,294,967,295.

The value in variable i crosses maximum range of unsigned integer after 6 iterations. Hence the overflow and negative numbers displayed.

If you want to represent larger numbers use `long long int` whose size is 64 bits and the range is from −9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807.